Prove that $\int_X \limsup f_n \, d\mu \geq \limsup \int_X f_n \, d\mu$
Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions such that there is a non-negative measurable function $F$ satisyfing
$$\int_X F \, d \mu < \infty \hspace{1cm} |f_n| \leq F  \mathrm{\hspace{0.2cm} for \, \, all \, \,} n$$
Prove that
$$\int_X \limsup f_n \, d\mu \geq \limsup \int_X f_n \, d\mu$$
Now, the most glaring tool of use here is the dominated convergence theorem. Let $f= \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$. If $f_n \to f$ then as $|f_n| \leq F$ then $\int f_n \to \int f$. But we do not know that the limit function $f$ exists. Hence, we must work with $\limsup_n f_n$. What can be done now?
EDIT: This answer utilizes Ryszard's suggestion to use Fatou on $F-f_n$:
Let $g_n = F-f_n$. Then by Fatou's lemma, we know that
\begin{align}
\int \liminf g_n  &\underbrace{\color{gray}{ \leq \int g} \leq \liminf \int g_n}_{\mathrm{Fatou}} \\ 
\iff \int \liminf \{F-f_n\} &\leq \liminf \int F-f_n \\
\iff \int \limsup f_n &\geq \limsup \int f_n
\end{align}
where the text in $\color{gray}{\mathrm{gray}}$ shows where the limit function $g = \lim_n g_n$ would go in the context of Fatou's lemma; it is written in this way to remind us that the limit $g$ may not exist.

You may use the Fatou lemma for $F-f_n.$

The limit of $g_n$ may not exist.

@kieransquared Would it be safer to write $g_n = |F-f_n|$?

It still may not exist; take $f_n = (-1)^n \chi_E$ where $E$ is some finite measure subset of $X$. Then $F=1$ but $g_n$ still oscillates.

@kieransquared I have now updated my answer
